# Negative numbers in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, numbers, masm, irvine32

So, in x86 assembly an if statement in positive number works but i am not sure this works....
I am using the Irvine library
so here is the snippet

```
        .IF xPos <= -117
        call UpdatePlayer
        dec xPos
        call DrawPlayer
        jmp gameLoop
        .ELSE
        jmp gameLoop
        .ENDIF
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided your *xPos* variable is a dword, use next code:

```
.IF SDWORD PTR xPos <= -117
  call UpdatePlayer
  dec xPos
  call DrawPlayer
.ENDIF
jmp gameLoop
```

You didn't need the `.ELSE` clause. Just put `jmp gameLoop` outside of the structure.

Comment: Or better, don't use this MASM "high level" stuff at all, and just `cmp dword ptr [xPos], -117` / `jnle gameLoop` / fall into call/dec/call / `jmp gameLoop`.  No point having MASM emit a `jcc` to a `jmp`, just jump to gameLoop directly if the call/dec/call shouldn't run.  But you can't get fully efficient asm for that with those `.IF` macros or whatever they're called.  The other advantage is that you don't have to use an esoteric MASM-specific stuff like `sdword`, just a normal `cmp` and a signed-compare JCC condition whose semantic meaning comes right from the `<=`.

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate it :), i hope you have a good day,
i am relatively new in assembly.